# Почему не перехватывается исключение NameError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Немогу понять, почему не перехватывается исключение `NameError`. Что не так с кодом?

```
def chek(args):
    c = 1
    while c == 1:
        try:
            count = 0
            for a in args:
                args[count] = int(a)
                count += 1
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            del args[count]
        except NameError:
            print(count)
            args[count] = ''
        else:
            c = 0
    return args

args = [5,'z',7,6,t,4]
args = chek(args)
```

Comment: Что делает Ваш код?

Comment: код выявляет элементы списка не соответствующие типу int и удаляет их, оставляя в списке только элементы приводимые к целочисленному типу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `t` не определена:

```py
args = [5, 'z', 7, 6, t, 4]
#                     ^
```

Вы не перехватываете это исключение. Чтобы перехватывать его:

```py
try:
    args = [5, 'z', 7, 6, t, 4]
except NameError:
    pass
```

---

Ваше решение можно упростить:

```py
def chek(li):
    i = 0
    while i < len(li):
        try:
            li[i] = int(li[i])
            i += 1
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            del li[i]
    return li
```

Comment: Да, именно это сообщение об ошибке, как раз и должно перехватывать исключение NameError. Мой вопрос в том, - почему cтрока `except NameError:` в моем коде, не перехватывает это сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: @user364464 исключение происходит ещё **до того**, как Вы вызываете функцию. В функции перехватывать `NameError` бесполезно.